# Leaflet - add class to marker icon on click

Tags: javascript, leaflet, marker

I have a simple leaflet map and some markers on it. To give the user a better experience i want to highlight a clicked marker. The best and simplest would be if i could just add an additional class to the clicked marker to work on css with it. But i dont know how and all i found wasn't answering my question or i just didn't understood it.

Javascript

```
//Set the marker icon

    var markerIcon = L.vectorIcon({
            className: 'markerIcon',
            svgHeight: 30,
            svgWidth: 30,
            shape: {r: '15', cx: '15', cy: '15'},
            style: {
                fill: '#73B0E1'
            }
    });


//Populate the map with markers

    var markers = L.markerClusterGroup({});
    if(mapID == 'mapPublic') {
        markers.addLayer(L.marker([50, 8], {icon: markerIcon})).on('click', onClick);
        markers.addLayer(L.marker([50, 8.1], {icon: markerIcon})).on('click', onClick);
        markers.addLayer(L.marker([50, 8.2], {icon: markerIcon})).on('click', onClick);
        markers.addLayer(L.marker([50.1, 8.1], {icon: markerIcon})).on('click', onClick);
    }

    map.addLayer(markers);


//Onclick Function for the markers

    function onClick() {}
```

How can i add a second class to the marker to work in css with it? I allready tried `this.classList.add('activeMarker')` but it didn't worked, i think because of leaflets marker logic.

Comment: hi you may add event mouseover and mouseout for each marher

Comment: For what reason? I just want to add a second class on click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The marker isn't a DOM object so it's no good trying to add classes to it.

If you're trying to style the icon, you could use

```
function onClick(e) {

e.layer._icon.classList.add('activemarker');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your tips. But if i add your code i just get an error. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined" if i use the classList and "Uncaught TypeError: L.DomUtil.AddClass is not a function" if i use the AddClass. Any suggestions?

Comment: Updated my answer with the full onClick function.

Comment: You're the sweetest! It's working now. Do you have a site where this with the "e" is explained in detail? Thank you!

Comment: Leaflet event handlers get called with an argument of an event object which you can inspect to interact with the context of the event. See https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#event-objects